# pandas count unique in each row

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Df with 2 columns

df:

```
fruit   location
apples  store,freezer,kitchen,livingroom,store,freezer,kitchen,livingroom
mango   store,freezer,kitchen,livingroom,store,freezer
orange  store,freezer,kitchen,freezer
```

I need to count the number of each location, incase there are multiple just consider them as one

## Code

```
df['counts'] = df.location.str.strip().str.split(',').apply(len)
```

## output

```
fruit   location
apples  8
mango   6
orange  5
```

When i try to use unique

## Code

```
df['counts'] = df.location.str.strip().str.split(',').unique().apply(len)
```

## Error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

## desired output

```
fruit   location
apples  4
mango   4
orange  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply` + `set` + `len`

```
df.location.str.split(',').apply(lambda x : len(set(x)))
Out[147]: 
0    4
1    4
2    4
Name: location, dtype: int64
```